# android activities lifecycle woes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

i have an application that i'm testing on the HTC one X.

Brief description:

My main activity is a tabbed application (using fragments). In one of the tabs, i have a button that takes the user to another activity via

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NoteActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

All this works fine. But in the NoteActivity, i have a textfield, and if the screen lock turns on, the NoteActivity gets destroyed right away, and when the user unlocks, my "Main" activity is started right away.

Also, when i move from the mainactivity -> noteactivity, my mainactivity is never destroyed, but when i go back (when the user is done with the note and clicks on "save"), the noteactivity is always destroyed right away.

Apparently, i need to store away the textfield contents in ondestroy and re-insert it in oncreate, but i don't understand why my second activity is always destroyed when the screen lock activates? My main activity is never destroyed.

I'm a little bit unsure about why Android does these lifecycle decisions. If somebody has any input, i'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

In many platforms/languages, the developer is responsible for managing memory. This gives rise to many bugs and poor performance issues.  The designers of Android have, in the main, taken this responsibility away from the developer and into the OS.  Android can destroy any of your activities at any time when they are not in the foreground,  Hence the provision of onPause() which is called before your activity goes to the background.

Why Android destroys your activity is non-determinant and depends on, amongst other factors; how much memory the device has; how much memory is free; what other apps and services are running; what kernel governors and power saving policies are in use etc etc,  To make this determinant would be a large and complex task so the design simply says once your activity goes to the background, Android may destroy it, sometimes with no further callbacks to you, so you should use the life cycle to save and restore state as needed.

Once you get used to it, it actually makes a lot of sense and is easy to work with.  I came from a Windows background and getting used to it takes some time but now I know it, it's fine.  I wouldn't say better or worse but a good solution for mobile devices.

It was the habitual thinking of desktop OSes that initial led me to seek out task managers and do things like system.exit() in apps but, leave Android to manage itself and it performs much better.

Live with the life cycle.

Comment: Simon, many thanks for your reply. I think i'm pretty well versed in the activity lifecycle ideas. My question was really about why it seems that one activity is "worth more" than the other. The scenario i describe leads the "stack" feature (where the latest activity is on top, back button goes back to previous activity) to, in my mind, not really function as advertised since i can see that for my app, the NoteActivity, which is the current one, is always destroyed, so that after the screen is re-activated, my main app's onCreate()-is always called.

Comment: Also, more interesting, this only happens on the HTC One X, not on any of my other Android test phones.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be patronising.  I assumed from your OP that you weren't comfortable with it.  a.  If you main app onCreate() is being called, then your app has been destroyed, not the activity.  b.  Why One X - see above list of factors that can affect.  c.  Why one activity and not another - resource usage?  Dalvik profiles app on resource usage so Android can make a decision on which are "high priority" things to kill once they leave the foreground.

Comment: Well, of course i screwed up in my description :) i meant that the "first" activity's onResume is called, not on create. Basically, my "launcher" activity never gets destroyed, but the noteactivity that i launch with intent from the mainactivity gets onDestroy()'ed every time, right away when the screenlock goes on. I find that weird, especially since it only happens on the One X. Cheers mate